# Google Optimize data wiping out daily

Tags: google-analytics, google-optimize

There doesn't seem to be many resources available for troubleshooting Google Optimize. I've been using the software for a year now with no issues. Optimize experiments update with new session data once or twice a day. As of recently, every time new data comes through, Optimize will zero out the session data.

The session data here looks correct until I click into the experiment:
[image: enter image here]

When I click into an experiment, you'll see the Experiment Sessions don't add up correctly. The experiment sessions were being tracked correctly last night, and they correctly added up to the total Collected Sessions.
[image]

Everything is tracking correctly until Google pulls in more data. I'm not sure what's causing this and I can't get support from their community or support team. Data was collecting fine a week ago. I haven't changed my experiment goals or how the tests are running. The only thing I've changed in that time is how many tests I'm running at the same time. I used to only run 1 test at a time, and I'm now running 3. None of the tested pages, or primary goals overlap. I do have some secondary goals that overlap. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was happening as a result of Google Analytics Goal Events being delayed. It can take 24-48 hours for website event data to come through.